# Updating Nested JSON Array with new key and value from another key

Tags: json, jq

I have have a JSON file where I have IDs with tasks.  Some tasks can be empty.  I want to put the ID into the tasks where tasks are not empty.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1961126,
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 70340700,
        "title": "Test1",
      },
      {
        "id": 69801130,
        "title": "Test15A",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1961126,
    "tasks": []
  }           
]
```

I would like to get the tasks array updated to look like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1961126,
    "tasks": [
      {
        **"sId":1961126,**
        "id": 70340700,
        "title": "Test1",
      },
      {
        **"sId":1961126,**
        "id": 69801130,
        "title": "Test15A",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1961126,
    "tasks": []
  }           
]
```

I can't figure out how to get the id from the object into the nested array.  Here is what I have come up with

```
jq 'map(.tasks[0]|select( . != null )|.sId = .id)' file.json
```

This is only pulling in the same id.  I have tired to put in `[].id` but I get a error `Cannot index number with string "id".`  I am still learning how to deal with nested arrays and objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the ID in a variable and add it as a new field to each array member.

```sh
 jq 'map(.id as $sId | .tasks[] += {$sId})' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jKtaM9Lv82)

Note #1: Get rid of the final `,` within each object (see the Demo), as it's not proper JSON.

Note #2: Object fields generally have no order, but if you want to have the propagated ID shown first, as seen in your expected output, you could try to replace `+= {$sId}` (which by itself is shorthand for `|= . + {$sId}`) with `|= {$sId} + .` to flip the order of generation ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tc2XmjlD4a)). Although there is no guarantee that it stays that way with further processing.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks for the notes as well.  I did get a  but I got around that by adding a ? after .tasks[].  Like so                                                                                                        jq 'map(.id as $sId | .tasks[]? += {$sId})' file.json

Comment: This means that `tasks` may indeed be `null` or even missing, not just `[]` (an empty array), as provided in your example. Using `?` is in fact the right way to handle those cases.